# Auto Layout: Responsive autoshrinking multiple labels

Tags: ios, interface-builder, autolayout, constraints, shrink

I make responsive skinning to support all iPhones from 4S till 6+. I have 2 labels and 3 buttons on one screen and I want to auto shrink them by using minimum font scale option and of course constraints. It is worth noting that for activate a flexibility of the text there one's needed to set line breaks option to any 'truncate' not a 'wrap'. But there I have an interesting issue: how I should to configure my 'Content Compression Resistance Priority' & 'Content Hugging Priority' to auto shrink both labels while I can't set the same 'Content Hugging Priority' value? Currently I can only set different priorities for labels and then one of them applied shrinking but another don't.

Answer (score 0):

This problem solved by setting equal height of 2nd label to 1st label corresponding to this explanation from Apple Documentation: [Auto Layout by Example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutbyExample/AutoLayoutbyExample.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH5-SW8)